# How do I remove default spacing around my header strip

Tags: html, css

Really simple code, the strip I created has a margin or spacing around it and I want it to fill the whole top side of the page.

```css
.header {
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the margins that come from body.

In CSS you can set the margins of body to 0.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also note that your `<html></html>` tags should be surrounding your entire html and your `<body></body>` tags should be holding all representational elements.

Answer (score 0):

To fill the whole top side of the page, you should set the `body`'s `margin` to `0px`.

```css
.header {
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader"></div>
```